# What is causing a NOT EQUAL TO and IN combination query to work just fine in MySQL but ignore the first condition in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, ubuntu-12.04

I am writing a Python script to run a query on a MySQL table. The high level flow is as follows:

> 1. Create Database
> 2. Create Table
> 3. Insert entries into table
> 4. Query table to get primary keys of the inserted entries based on some criteria

For example, I'll insert this data into the table:

```
page_URL               page_type>
mywebsite.com/blog     0
mywebsite.com/help     0
notmywebsite.com       98
```

Then I run this query:

```
SELECT 
    page_URL, pageID, page_type 
FROM dim_all_pages 
WHERE 
    page_type != 98 
    AND page_URL IN ('mywebsite.com/blog', 'notmywebsite.com', 'mywebsite.com/help')
```

The result I get, as expected, is as follows:

```
mywebsite.com/blog   1   0
mywebsite.com/help   2   0
```

But when I run the query via Python, I get the following result:

```
mywebsite.com/blog   1   0
mywebsite.com/help   2   0
notmywebsite.com     3   98
```

This makes no sense! Here is what my code looks like:

```
query = ["INSERT INTO dim_all_pages (page_URL, page_type) VALUES ( "]
query.append("SELECT page_URL, pageID, page_type FROM dim_all_pages WHERE page_type != 98 AND page_URL IN ( ")

for index, item in enumerate(page_list):
    query[0] = query[0] + "'" + item + "' , " + page_type(item) + " )"
    query[1] = query[1] + "'" + item + "'"
    if index + 1 < len(page_list):
        query[0] += ' , ( '
        query[1] += ' , '

query[1] += ' )'

try:

    # Insert pages
    con = get_con(loc,user,pw)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(query[0])

    # Create PSP
    cur.execute(query[1])
    psp = cur.fetchall()

    # Commit queries
    con.commit()

except mdb.Error, e:

    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
    sys.exit(1)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? This is messing with my mind right now!

Comment: I also copy-pasted the query generated in Python into MySQL and ran it, it worked just fine!

Comment: Can you show the output of `print(query)` just before the `try` statement starts ?

Comment: You are building your query as a string without using SQL parameters, always a risky business. Perhaps you are not building the query you think you are building?

Comment: The output is the same as the query I posted. I copy paste the output of `print(query[1])` into MySQL and run it, and it works just fine. This has to be something I am doing wrong in Python. 

I'll also look into SQLAlchemy to see if I can figure out a better way to do this.

Comment: Apart from SQL parameters, you also need to look into the `str.join()` method to build up strings with separators.

Comment: Alternatively, Martijn what do you recommend for building a query the "right" way?

Comment: So it turned out that the problem was completely somewhere else, totally unrelated. I feel like a total idiot, sorry guys!